# How to set header while creating Spring's RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

We can set a header to rest template while firing the call i.e. `restTemplate.exchange(postUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);`

where entity contains headers.

But for my requirement I want to set cookie header while creating the restTemplate itself and not while firing the actual call. I don't want to repeat the code of creating HttpEntity and setting headers to it.

Is there a way to set headers while creating restTemplate?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can inject your own `HttpMessageConverter` implementation which accepts all requests - `canWrite` returns `true`. And add desired headers within `write` method to the `HttpOutputMessage.getHeaders()`.

I remember as I overrided once `ClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest` to do something similar for other server-specific static header.

**UPDATE**

> From the code of `RestTemplate.doWithRequest` you can see if there is no `request.body` then it reads `headers` from the `request entity`.

In that case you can simply extend `RestTemplate` and return from the overridden `httpEntityCallback`  your own `RequestCallback`.

Comment: Hey Artem,
Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but it doesn't work for calls without request body :( which includes almost all the get calls. 
<br>
From the code of RestTemplate.doWithRequest you can see if there is no request.body then it reads headers from the request entity. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Good. Thanks for pointing that out. Right, for `GET` it doesn't use `messageConverters`. See an update to my answer.